# What should I do in order to get access to the object created at program's runtime?

Tags: java, design-patterns, runtime

I'm trying to make an interactive console program which creates hierarchy of boxes and balls contained in them. I didn't figure out how to create nested boxes and how to navigate between boxes. The problem is by what method's type I should create new instances of Box. If type is void, I can't get reference to that object anymore. If type is not void I have to store references somewhere. What are keywords in google to solve this case? Is there any pattern for that?

The problem is that every changes to hierarchy I can do only at runtime, so no hardcoded instantiations are allowed.

Comment: If you don't store a reference to an object (Box or Ball or anything else) it will terminate and be garbage-collected. - There are enough dynamic data structures in java.util to permit the dynamic storage of reference in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is that you have to represent the containment in your data structures:

- An class of objects that can contain other objects needs a field which is collection (e.g. a list or set) of references to the objects that it contains.
- A class of objects that can be contained by other objects needs a field that refers to an object's current container.
- Some classes of objects can be both containers and contained.